# How to fix PHP "Invalid Argument Supplied For Foreach()"

Tags: php

```
<?php
include "config.php";
if(isset($_FILES['berkas'])){
    foreach ($_FILES['berkas']['name'] as $file=>$name){
        $filename = date('Ymd-His',time()).mt-rand().'-'.$name;
        try{
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['berkas']['tmp_name'][$file], 'uploads/'.$filename));{
                $stmt= $db->prepare("insert into multipleload values('',?)");
                $stmt ->bindParam(1,$filename);
                $stmt->execute();

            }
        } catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e;
        }

    }
}   
?>
```

Error is on line 3
I've already tried if(is_array()){ } but it doesn't stop error message.

I'm trying to make a document submission php file btw. I've looked through previous posts and have really only found that clearly its not getting an array.

Comment: What does `$_FILES['berkas']['name']` return?

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` expects the variable that will loop through to be an `array` .
and it seems that `$_FILES['berkas']['name']` is not an array it is represent a string of the file name so . you should use it like this

```
foreach ($_FILES['berkas'] as $file => $name ){ 
    // your code here 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's because the structure of `$_FILES` is as follows:

```
$_FILES[fieldname] => array(
    [name] => array( /* these arrays are the size you expect */ )
    [type] => array( /* these arrays are the size you expect */ )
    [tmp_name] => array( /* these arrays are the size you expect */ )
    [error] => array( /* these arrays are the size you expect */ )
    [size] => array( /* these arrays are the size you expect */ )
);
```

So when you're trying to iterate over _FILES you're supplying an array as opposite to an associative array. Instead, your foreach should look like:

```
foreach ($_FILES['berkas'] as $type=>$value) {
    // if $type is 'name', do something
}
```

If you're trying to iterate over *just* the name, you can do

```
foreach ($_FILES['berkas']['name'] as $name) {
    // if $type is 'name', do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to loop through the $_FILES superglobal like so:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file => $data) {
```

where `$data` will be an array containing keys 'name', 'type', 'size', etc. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php for more info about how this works.